# Using ContextResolver to register ObjectMapper in runtime

Tags: client, jax-rs, java-ee-7, objectmapper

We're using JAX-RS (Jersey implementation) to call to external systems.
On JAX-RS Client's creation I'm registering the below context resolver to use custom ObjectMapper:

```
public class JacksonObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>
{

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) 
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES, false);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS, true);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

        return mapper;
    }   
}
```

But I don't want to have the ObjectMapper defined in JacksonObjectMapperProvider. I want JacksonObjectMapperProvider to be able to retrieve it in runtime from somewhere, or have someone set the ObjectMapper on JacksonObjectMapperProvider.

I cannot do something like bellow, because the ObjectMapper is defined on some instance that creating the jax-rs Client. And here I don't have a reference to that instance:

```
public class JacksonObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>
{

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) 
    {
        return someService.getObjectMapper();
    }   
}
```

Is there another way to do it?
Is there a way to pass data to JacksonObjectMapperProvider when registering on Client?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easier then I thought, instead of registering the class:

```
ClientConfig clConfig = new ClientConfig();
client.register(JacksonObjectMapperProvider.class);
```

as I did, you can register an instance of the class, and on instance creation pass whatever you want:

```
ClientConfig clConfig = new ClientConfig();
client.register(new JacksonObjectMapperProvider(objectMapper));
```

The updated provider:

```
public class JacksonObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>
{

    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    public JacksonObjectMapperProvider(ObjectMapper mapper)
    {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) 
    {
        return mapper;
    }   
}
```